# How to change castor-maven-plugin's default code generator version

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml, castor

I am using org.codehaus.mojo:castor-maven-plugin version 2.1. It defaultly uses castor version 1.3.1 for code generation.Is there any other way  to change default code generator version 1.3.3-rc1.

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>castor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.1</version>
 <dependencies>

 <dependency> 
 <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
 <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.3-rc1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
 <artifactId>castor-codegen</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.3-rc1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
 <version>2.6</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
 <artifactId>castor-xml-schema</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.3-rc1</version>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <executions>
 <execution> ...
```

followed by execution tasks.

If we specify the castor version which we want to use for code generation  in dependencies it will take that particular version for code generation. For REF 2.5.2.1. Configuration of this link 
http://castor.codehaus.org/reference/html/xml.code.generator.html